# Get module config params

Tags: yii, yii2

In every module i have config(with params and etc.).
Registration

```
\Yii::configure($this, require __DIR__ . '/config/config.php');
```

How I get params from another module? For example: in user module i need params from product module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the module ref  eg using the related id (eg: user)

```
$moduleUser = \Yii::$app->getModule('user');
```

then you can access  to the related  param  (eg: myParam)

```
$myParam = $moduleUser->params['myParam'];
```

Comment: thanks. Are you know, if i use `\Yii::$app->getModule('user')` few times, module instance create every time or instance is singleton?

Comment: getModule  .. should return a singleton  .. see  https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-module#getModule()-detail